# NPM ENOENT errors when running Npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I've been trying to make a RoVer-based bot for my Discord server, but I keep getting ENOENT errors whenever I run npm Install.

I know there are other posts like this, but none of the answers have worked, and they aren't exactly the same problem that I'm having. I've already tried reinstalling Node.js and NPM, making sure the package.json is there, restarting, and running as administrator. **I am currently running Windows 10 version 1903, Node version 12.13.0, npm version 6.12.0.**

### Here's the output:

````js
C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management>npm install
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\type-b1627078\array\ensure.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\es6-map-8f9402c7\primitive\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\es6-set-0c58b760\lib\iterator.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\type-b1627078\array\is.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\es6-iterator-44858e44\test\array.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\es6-set-0c58b760\lib\primitive-iterator.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\es6-iterator-44858e44\test\for-of.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\es6-iterator-44858e44\test\get.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\inquirer-1bea01d1\lib\utils\events.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\es6-iterator-44858e44\test\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\inquirer-1bea01d1\lib\utils\paginator.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\es6-iterator-44858e44\test\is-iterable.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\inquirer-1bea01d1\lib\utils\readline.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\es6-iterator-44858e44\test\string.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\inquirer-1bea01d1\lib\utils\screen-manager.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\es6-iterator-44858e44\test\valid-iterable.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\inquirer-1bea01d1\lib\utils\utils.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\readable-stream-cd75c034\lib\internal\streams\BufferList.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\readable-stream-cd75c034\lib\internal\streams\destroy.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\readable-stream-cd75c034\lib\internal\streams\stream-browser.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\readable-stream-cd75c034\lib\internal\streams\stream.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\eslint-9d02902d\lib\util\patterns\letters.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\eslint-9d02902d\lib\code-path-analysis'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\type-b1627078\test\array-length\coerce.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\type-b1627078\test\array-length\ensure.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\type-b1627078\test\array-like'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\es5-ext-7d8b429e\array\#\map\implement.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\es5-ext-7d8b429e\array\#\map\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\es5-ext-7d8b429e\array\#\map\is-implemented.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\es5-ext-7d8b429e\array\#\map\shim.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\es5-ext-7d8b429e\array\#\remove.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\es5-ext-7d8b429e\array\#\separate.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\core-js-70848f9b\fn\array\virtual\copy-within.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\core-js-70848f9b\fn\array\virtual\entries.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\core-js-70848f9b\fn\array\virtual\every.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\core-js-70848f9b\fn\array\virtual\fill.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\core-js-70848f9b\fn\array\virtual\filter.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\core-js-70848f9b\fn\array\virtual\find-index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\core-js-70848f9b\fn\array\virtual\find.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\core-js-70848f9b\fn\array\virtual\flat-map.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\core-js-70848f9b\fn\array\virtual\flatten.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\core-js-70848f9b\fn\array\virtual\for-each.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\core-js-70848f9b\fn\array\virtual\includes.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\core-js-70848f9b\fn\array\virtual\index-of.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\core-js-70848f9b\fn\array\virtual\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\core-js-70848f9b\fn\array\virtual\iterator.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\core-js-70848f9b\fn\array\virtual\join.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\core-js-70848f9b\fn\array\virtual\keys.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\core-js-70848f9b\fn\array\virtual\last-index-of.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\core-js-70848f9b\fn\array\virtual\map.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\core-js-70848f9b\fn\array\virtual\reduce-right.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\core-js-70848f9b\fn\array\virtual\reduce.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\core-js-70848f9b\fn\array\virtual\slice.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\core-js-70848f9b\fn\array\virtual\some.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\core-js-70848f9b\fn\array\virtual\sort.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\core-js-70848f9b\fn\array\virtual\values.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\core-js-70848f9b\fn\asap.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\core-js-70848f9b\fn\clear-immediate.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\es5-ext-7d8b429e\math\atanh\implement.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\es5-ext-7d8b429e\math\atanh\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\es5-ext-7d8b429e\math\atanh\is-implemented.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\es5-ext-7d8b429e\math\atanh\shim.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\es5-ext-7d8b429e\math\cbrt'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\core-js-70848f9b\fn\error\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\core-js-70848f9b\fn\error\is-error.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\es5-ext-7d8b429e\math\log10\implement.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\es5-ext-7d8b429e\math\log10\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\es5-ext-7d8b429e\math\log10\is-implemented.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\es5-ext-7d8b429e\math\log10\shim.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\Desktop\AMC Pilot Management\node_modules\.staging\es5-ext-7d8b429e\math'
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/discordjs/Commando.git
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\terri_3irl9af\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-10-23T23_59_46_552Z-debug.log```
````

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue? I am srtuggling with something similar, and haven't found the culprit.

Answer (score 2):

You have this error near the bottom of your log:

```
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
```

This means you do not have git installed on your machine. You need to install [git](https://git-scm.com/downloads) from here: https://git-scm.com/downloads.

I had the same problem as you, and once I installed git, the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds a bit like it could be a permissions issue. Are you in the root of your project?

From: https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/261

> if you are pretty new to Node/github/etc., you might be doing what I
>   did -- cloned a repo and then forgot to cd into the repo directory --
>   so npm can't find a package.json file, so it gives you that big
>   convoluted error message.

I guess you have a package.json file in the same dir you're running the tests from??

Comment: I have the package.json in the same directory and did CD into the folder, I'm also quite experienced with node and NPM.

Comment: Permissions should be fine. Although this is not the administrator account, I have tried running it as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

For me installing `npx` globally helped.

Using : `npm i npx -g`

Hope this helps. Thank you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: it helped in my case

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error when used NextJS. I solved this problem just run yarn dev again. You should do it after install npm-packages.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
npx npkill
```

It will ask you if you want install npkill, then you should remove node_modules with spacebar.

If you removed node_modules, then install node_modules again

```
npm i
```

Answer (score 0):

u have opened some file of AppData etc in the vs code thats why terminal provide error

go to the vs code => open folder  => select project folder only
and then vs code will show some already opening files cut them
and then terminate